# How to prevent Magento from removing disabled items from cart?

Tags: multistore, addtocart

I'm developing a store that the cart is shared with all stores.

I achieved the quote id sharing, but when an product that is disabled in a store is added to cart, next time that I enter in the *checkout/cart* page, the item is gone.

I want that the product stays on cart and add an message saying that the item is not available in the store that the user will checkout.

Someone have done that before?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I am finding the same solution.

Comment: @Hardik, unfortunately, no.

But I found that what made the item missing in the cart is the cart: somehow the user state (if it is logged in or not) creates a new cart and merge the guest cart. At this moment the item vanishes.

I stopped working in this project so I couldn't get any further in the resolution of our problem.